# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, autobahn

I am getting no Websocket connection between client script and server.

It is working fine in my local environment.

Also I am following this [link](http://socketo.me/docs/push).

Here's a server script that initializes the websocket server and listens for the client connection to `8080` port.

```
public function run()
{
    $loop   = Factory::create();
    $pusher = new Pusher;
    $context = new Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

    // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $webSock = new Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new IoServer(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

And here's the client script:

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8080',
    function() {
        /* subscribe to following topics */
        conn.subscribe('new_order', function(topic, data) ..
```

Again, this is working fine in the local setup.

Also to note, my application is hosted using a specified port from docker container.

```
http://192.168.12.52:8094/xyz/new/....
```

I also tried specifying the IP in the client script:

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://192.168.12.52:8080',
    function() {
        /* subscribe to following topics */
        conn.subscribe('new_order', function(topic, data) ...
```

In which case I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.11.32:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an ssl certificate issue. I think new browsers versions have problem with web sockets without ssl. you may have self signed certificate. try https://192.168.12.52:8080 and if you saw an invalid certificate error (something like: Your connection is not secure or Your connection is not private) click advance or add exception then try again with the same browser. also you can use wss:// instead of ws://.